# Kentico 8.2 Content Staging between two servers sharing the same IP

Tags: iis-7.5, kentico, staging

I am trying to set up content staging between our Dev and Staging servers.  They are using sub-domains i.e. dev..com and staging..com.  They also reside on the same physical machine and share the same IP. 
The issue I'm running into is that Staging can sync with Dev, but Dev cannot sync with Staging.  However I can successfully sync with both Dev and Staging from my localhost.  I also noticed that when I RDP into the server, I can browse to dev..com, but not staging..com.  Externally I can browse to either one.

Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Does the server have a local hosts file with any entries for urls? If not, you can add your custom urls ([local ip] dev.domain.com) which will allow the server to see the sites on the server.

Comment: Can you verify that DEV can talk to Staging in staging app -> servers -> staging server? it should show you an error if it can't - what is that error?

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot resolve staging..com locally, that means your dev cannot see staging, thus it cannot sync data to it. But your staging can see dev locally, so that other way works. So please add a local host entry for staging..com

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your network setup you may need to check to see if there are restrictions in place for one domain to "talk" to another.  If you're in a DMZ, there is a good chance you're making a full round trip from dev.domain.com to staging.domain.com and visa versa when going from staging to dev and access to dev may not be publically available.

My suggestion is to try to access your domains outside of your local network (at home) and see if you can access either.  If you can't then contact your network admin and see if they can track the issue down with some other tools.